# Сортировка списков в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет.
Нужна помощь со списками в Python.
Имею следующий список:
`[('1649298461', 0, 1000.0, 'test', '2023-03-01'), ('1534935986', 0, 900.0, 'testt', '2023-03-22'), ('1534935986', 0, 99.0, 'testt', '2023-03-22')]`
Нужно отсортировать список таким образом, что бы на выходе получилась следующая информация:
`[('1649298461', 0, 1000.0, 'test', '2023-03-01'), ('1534935986', 0, 999.0, 'testt', '2023-03-22')]`
То есть, мне нужно исключить совпадения по 3 индексу списка, и если такие совпадения будут найдены, то сложить 2-ые индексы меж собой.
Совпадений может быть много!

Comment: `itertools.groupby`, например, ну или через `Pandas` тоже `groupby`

Comment: А при чём тут sqlite3? Если вы вытаскиваете эти данные из базы, то, может, просто написать все эти действия внутри sql-запроса да и всё?

Comment: @andreymal можете помочь с запросом?

Comment: Во-первых, для этого нужно знать структуру таблицы, а во-вторых, не очень понятно что делать с остальными индексами при совпадениях - в показанном вами примере они все одинаковые, но что если вдруг окажутся неодинаковые?

Comment: Так опять же `group by` по тем полям, которые должны совпадать, а которое суммировать, то делаете `SUM`